# How to fix KeyError: 'alpha' while fitting data with fitter package?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting, anaconda3, model-fitting

I installed `fitter` on my anaconda in order to use it for collective curve fitting of real data on many distributions simultanously and choose the best fitting. However, it seems that out of the box, it has some sort of bug. Can anyone let me know what it is and how to fix it?

```
File "c:\Users\username\Desktop\Project\PythonTool\calculator\graph-analyzer\my_script.py", line 253, in curve_finder
    print(f.get_best(method='sumsquare_error'))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\fitter\fitter.py", line 366, in get_best
    params = self.fitted_param[name]
KeyError: 'alpha'
```

Per Mikuszefski's request, here is a MWE to reproduce the error message:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from fitter import Fitter
from typing import List

#constants
data: List = [('A', 1, 'Company1', 10), ('B', 4, 'Company2', 20), ('C', 3, 'Company3', 5),
              ('D', 3, 'Company3', 1), ('E', 2, 'Company1', 2), ('F', 4, 'Company3', 9),
              ('G', 3, 'Company3', 7), ('H', 2, 'Company1', 1), ('I', 4, 'Company2', 15),
              ('J', 8, 'Company1', 1), ('K', 2, 'Company2', 3), ('L', 4, 'Company2', 6),
              ('M', 6, 'Company2', 3), ('N', 2, 'Company2', 10), ('O', 4, 'Company3', 10),
              ('P', 3, 'Company1', 1), ('Q', 2, 'Company2', 5), ('R', 4, 'Company1', 4)]


#Main driving function
def main() -> None:
    dataset = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Label', 'Degree', 'Affiliation', 'Duration'])

    degrees = dataset["Degree"].values
    f = Fitter(degrees)
    f.fit()
    print(f.get_best(method='sumsquare_error'))
    print(f.summary())
  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi, can you try to provide a stand alone "working" example that reproduces your error? (My experience has shown that very often this already solves the issue, but anyhow helps here a lot)

Comment: I tried too but I am not understanding the error message to reverse engineer it.

Comment: Right, don't worry; first part of the comment remains valid, though.

Comment: Well, your working example is actually working on my machine and not throwing an error. I get a few warnings, though, that three distributions are skipped as they take more than 30 secs.

Comment: Really? that's weird.

Comment: Maybe we have different versions, as in my source code the only alphas I find are for plotting. ( I have 1.4.0 )